# Is it possible to add image as background to edit text keeping underline in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I want to set dots as background to edit text as inputType password but also as a hint and keeping underline like this.

[image]

Is it possible to do it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `background` image your `edittext` and use `View` for `UnderLine`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp">
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Any thing you want"
        android:background="@drawable/image"/>
 <View
     android:id="@+id/view"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:background="#929292" />
</FrameLayout>
```

try this its help you..

Comment: I have tried to put a background image and never appears, only if i put drawableStart or drawableEnd, Do you know why? If not I will use an image on top the edit text. Thank you so much.

Comment: my solution gives you whole `fill_parent` line but your line cut it out for one single character or digit wise...only customize your `edittext` given your satisfy output

Answer (score 1):

You could use several EditTexts in your layout and jump back and forth depending on the user input. Initialize all of them with HINT image. Then load the Black dot image whenever user inputs a key.

You could tweak with override onKeyPressed() method.

onKeyPressed -> if the key pressed is a letter/number, set the image to background,
if the key pressed is delete, set the hint image to the background and clear that edit text.

Hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  very usefull. I tried like this but the behaviour is not what I expected as the image has to be on start or end of the edit text and this one has length limited to 1. Maybe it's easier to do @MD Kahli's way

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set back Ground Image In Edit Text.

XML code :

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Any thing you want"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
```